# Contributing to the cause of biology (beyond research)

Tags: communication, internship, science-communication

I've been studying microbiology for a while (undergrad sophomore). I've been finding something to do other than my regular academic work and projects.
Someone told me that Nature allows freelancers to edit some articles. Is it true ? 
What are some other places where I can use my biology/writing/communication skills to help the cause of science and maybe even build my CV (last part is optional, I'm basically bored and will do anything if seems fun)

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on-topic here cause there is a specific freelancing SE and maybe people there could help you better with your question cause your question is pointing to freelancing more than the academia or an academic issue or question. So, I suggest to migrate this question maybe to freelancing SE.

Comment: I specifically wished to work on tracks of science so i didn't knew where to post it. Thanks though

Comment: This might be of interest to you: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/48886/10643

Comment: I'm not sure the edited title helps: You aren't a hobbyist, you're an academic. Maybe "_Contributing to the cause of biology (beyond academic research)_"

Comment: Go and count bugs or whatever takes your fancy. There are many areas of biology where data generation is underfunded and hobbyists (often academic hobbyists) are the main source of data. This can then lead to a study such as this one: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0185809

Comment: @Roland I’m not sure if OP takes your advice could reach his/her goal or not... particularly I don’t agree “Go and count bugs or whatever”! I mean of course freelancers don’t have salary but it doesn’t mean they should be hired for some activities like “counting bugs”! Which may not have any outcome at least in short term where the OP has concern to build his/her CV in near future. If these kind of advices are given to OP, I prefer to advise his/her to do some tutoring which may at least have some good impacts on his CV in comparison to “counting bugs or whatever”.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer From what do you infer that OP is looking for career building activities? "I'm basically bored and will do anything if seems fun" Also, people who count bugs are highly specialized and well regarded experts. Unfortunately, there are almost no academic positions for them and therefore the field relies on volunteers.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a dedicated portal called Biotechnology, which has some promising content right now. A formal categorization of topics is available, also major keywords have a longer description. The problem is, that many specialized articles are missing right now. They are only available in a dedicated research encyclopedia which is sold as a commercial product for 2000 US$. That means, there is a knowledge gap between the content in Wikipedia and the content in encyclopedias used by researchers. So if somebody has too much time he can try to transfer the knowledge from Academia into the public domain and create some Wikipedia stubs. This would help to bring Open Science forward.

Answer (score 0):

Commercial editorial services are available. You could volunteer to help or seek part-time employment.

Comment: Can you desribe the “Commercial editorial services” a bit more?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Can you explain the question? I can only break down the words (there are editorial services that charge), which probably isn't what you want.